# Nearest number to set of numbers

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity

Suppose that we have a set of number as `P = { p1, p2, p3, ..., pn }` ( length(P) = `n` ) and choose a number as `q`. So I want to find an algorithm to get the nearest member of set `P` to `q`. So the question is: What structure is appropriate to keep data ( `p1, p2, ...` ) and algorithms to find nearest member of P to q in `O(1)` time complexity.

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but its solution is probably related to this question, asked like 2 minutes ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8262606/dynamic-range-search

Comment: I means nearest member of `P` to q!

Comment: are there any constraints on the numbers?

Comment: No, we have N numbers with any values. You can suppose that these numbers are set of points in 1D graph.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You cannot get O(1) complexity. The closest you can get to that is O(lg lg n) by using a van Emde Boas tree.
2. If the set is static, use a sorted vector and binary search (O(lg n)) to find the nearest element.
3. If the set can change between queries, use an appropriate data structure for maintaining dynamic sets (e.g., AVL or red-black tree).

Comment: Are you sure about O(1) complexity ? It is the one of question that my teacher give me to solve it! The question wants me to introduce O(1) complexity algorithm :-/ !

Comment: Yes, unless in the special case where "numbers" in P are part of a finite set, or if the metric is unusual, you won't be able to get O(1).

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez : Thanks for your response :) I think O(lg lg n) is so closest to O(1) and the means of my teacher introduce the algorithm of using van Emde Boas tree. :)

Comment: @zvrba : Thanks for your post, i accepted your answer, because i think it is closest to my required answer :)

Comment: Perhaps the wanted solution is something similar to radix sort. Off course this works only if the set P is constant and even then it's `O(pn-p1)`, kind of `pseudo-O(1)`.

Comment: @ypercube: The set of P is constant, but putting it in appropriate data structure and getting closest member of P to q is my question. What data structure and what algorithm ?

Comment: @Hossein: if the set P is constant, then n is constant and O(log(n)) = O(log(log(n)) = O(1)… of course you would not try to enumerate all the neighbors of q to find the closest one which is in the set, would you?

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez: We have set P and number q! We should insert these set members to an `data structure` that is my question! If these numbers insert to the data structure that sort this members, i think it is not needing to enumerate all neighbors!

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of getting `O(1)` time complexity is if you can use `O(pn)` space and `O(pn)` time to preorder P and allocate values in a `pn` size array.

Preorder `P` so `p1` is the minimum and `pn` is the maximum (I assume that they are integers.) Then store in an array with size `(pn-p1+1)` the values:

```
A(p1) = p1
for  i = 2  to  n
    for  q = p(i-1)+1  to  (p(i-1)+p(i))/2
        A(q) = p(i-1)
    for  q = (p(i-1)+p(i))/2  to  p(i) 
        A(q) = p(i)
```

Then all you have to check for a certain `q` is:

```
if q < A(p1)
    closest = A(p1)
elif q > A(pn)
    closest = A(pn)
else
    closest = A(q)
```

Comment: I have a feeling that my answer is so wrong... Feel free to downvote.

Comment: Could you please explain more about the first part of code in your answer ? ( `A(p1) = p1 ... X(q) = p(i)` )

Comment: It essentially precalculates the closest `pi` for all integers between `p1` and `pn`.

Comment: @ypercube Since the questions asks "What structure is appropriate to keep data [and] to find nearest member of P to q in O(1) time complexity" you probably are ok with that O(1) lookup time and O(p_n - p_1) preprocessing time.  A minor problem - `A((p(i-1)+p(i))/2)` might be off by 1; your code assigns it first to `p(i-1)` and then to `p(i)`, and probably half the time only one of them is correct.