# Efficient Way to Find the Difference of a Period and Set of Ranges in Ruby

Tags: ruby, algorithm

I've got a number of time ranges in Ruby:

```
period = Time.parse('8:00am')..Time.parse('8:00pm')
incidents = [
  Time.parse('7:00am')..Time.parse('9:00am'),
  Time.parse('1:00pm')..Time.parse('3:00pm'),
  Time.parse('1:30pm')..Time.parse('3:30pm'),
  Time.parse('7:00pm')..Time.parse('9:00pm'),
]
```

I'm trying to get an array of incident free blocks within the period. For the above that'd be:

```
[
  Time.parse('9:00am')..Time.parse('1:00pm')
  Time.parse('3:30pm')..Time.parse('7:00pm')
]
```

From the above it is possible for incidents to overlap or extend outside the period. Do any operations exist on range or something similar that would make this sort of calculation simpler?

Comment: If this is a practical application and you're using PostgreSQL, you ought to consider using the [date math functionality](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html) via SQL query instead of handling inside of your application logic.

Comment: If you're looking at this purely from an algorithmic development standpoint, [this question/answer should give you some fodder for consderation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193477/fast-algorithm-to-quickly-find-the-range-a-number-belongs-to-in-a-set-of-ranges?rq=1).

Comment: @coreyward unfortunately the data isn't stored in a SQL database. I'm also not really clear if the SQL version would be easier based on the link (if I were to import into PSQL prior).

Comment: @Stussa about how many entries in the respective sets are we talking?

Comment: @Felix between five to ten incidents need to be checked per period

Comment: How fine are the time increments for your periods and incidents? Are 30-minute blocks as small as they will get?

Comment: @moveson they can be any duration

Comment: I don't think anything native in Range is going to help with this problem. Ruby has some nice methods for array subtraction, but you can't get an array if you can't convert to an enumerable, and you can't convert Time to an enumerable. If you were working with finite blocks of time, you could convert your ranges of time blocks to arrays, subtract the incidents, and convert back to ranges without much trouble. This might work for minutes. If you need seconds, the arrays would get pretty large.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let `full_range` be a range and `ranges` be an array of ranges, representing what the asker termed `period` and `incidents`, respectively. I've assumed the elements contained in all ranges can be any objects, provided they can be compared with the applicable class' method `<=>` and that the module [Comparable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Comparable.html) has been `include`d.

**Code**

```
def uncovered_ranges(full_range, ranges)
  ucrs = [full_range]
  ranges.each do |r|
    ucrs = ucrs.flat_map do |ucr|
      if ucr.first >= r.last || ucr.last <= r.first
        ucr 
      elsif r.first <= ucr.first && r.last >= ucr.last
        nil
      elsif r.first <= ucr.first && r.last < ucr.last
        r.last..ucr.last
      elsif r.first > ucr.first && r.last >= ucr.last
        ucr.first..r.first
      else
        [ucr.first..r.first, r.last..ucr.last]
      end
    end.compact
  end
  ucrs
end
```

**Examples**

```
full_range = 1..20
ranges = [3..4, 6..8, 10..12, 8..14, 16..17, 20..20]   

uncovered_ranges(full_range, ranges)
  #=> [1..3, 4..6, 14..16, 17..20]

require 'time'

full_range = Time.parse('8:00am')..Time.parse('8:00pm')
  #=> 2016-12-22 08:00:00 -0800..2016-12-22 20:00:00 -0800 

ranges = [
  Time.parse('7:00am')..Time.parse('9:00am'),
  Time.parse('1:00pm')..Time.parse('3:00pm'),
  Time.parse('1:30pm')..Time.parse('3:30pm'),
  Time.parse('7:00pm')..Time.parse('9:00pm'),
]
  #=> [2016-12-22 07:00:00 -0800..2016-12-22 09:00:00 -0800,
  #    2016-12-22 13:00:00 -0800..2016-12-22 15:00:00 -0800,
  #    2016-12-22 13:30:00 -0800..2016-12-22 15:30:00 -0800,
  #    2016-12-22 19:00:00 -0800..2016-12-22 21:00:00 -0800] 

uncovered_ranges(full_range, ranges)
  #=> [2016-12-22 09:00:00 -0800..2016-12-22 13:00:00 -0800,
  #    2016-12-22 15:30:00 -0800..2016-12-22 19:00:00 -0800]
```

**Explanation**

Perhaps the easiest and most through way for me to explain what's going on is to insert some `puts` statements and run the code for the first example above.

```
def uncovered_ranges(full_range, ranges)
  ucrs = [full_range]
  puts "ucrs initially=#{ucrs}"
  ranges.each do |r|
    puts "\ncovering range r=#{r}"
    ucrs = ucrs.flat_map do |ucr|
      puts "  range uncovered so far ucr=#{ucr}"
      if ucr.first >= r.last || ucr.last <= r.first
        puts "  in if #1, returning #{ucr}"
        ucr 
      elsif r.first <= ucr.first && r.last >= ucr.last
        puts "  in if #2, returning nil"
        nil
      elsif r.first <= ucr.first && r.last < ucr.last
        puts "  in if #3, returning #{r.last..ucr.last}"
        r.last..ucr.last
      elsif r.first > ucr.first && r.last >= ucr.last
        puts "  in if #4, returning #{ucr.first..r.first}"
        ucr.first..r.first
      else
        puts "  in else, returning #{[ucr.first..r.first, r.last..ucr.last]}"
       [ucr.first..r.first, r.last..ucr.last]
      end
    end.tap { |u| puts "ucrs after processing range #{r}=#{u}" }.
        compact.
        tap { |u| puts "ucrs after compact=#{u}" }
  end
  ucrs
end

uncovered_ranges 1..20, [3..4, 6..8, 10..12, 8..14, 16..17, 20..20]
```

prints the following.

```
ucrs initially=[1..20]
```

```
covering range r=3..4
  range uncovered so far ucr=1..20
  in else, returning [1..3, 4..20]
ucrs after processing range 3..4=[1..3, 4..20]
ucrs after compact=[1..3, 4..20]
```

```
covering range r=6..8
  range uncovered so far ucr=1..3
  in if #1, returning 1..3
  range uncovered so far ucr=4..20
  in else, returning [4..6, 8..20]
ucrs after processing range 6..8=[1..3, 4..6, 8..20]
ucrs after compact=[1..3, 4..6, 8..20]
```

```
covering range r=10..12
  range uncovered so far ucr=1..3
  in if #1, returning 1..3
  range uncovered so far ucr=4..6
  in if #1, returning 4..6
  range uncovered so far ucr=8..20
  in else, returning [8..10, 12..20]
ucrs after processing range 10..12=[1..3, 4..6, 8..10, 12..20]
ucrs after compact=[1..3, 4..6, 8..10, 12..20]
```

```
covering range r=8..14
  range uncovered so far ucr=1..3
  in if #1, returning 1..3
  range uncovered so far ucr=4..6
  in if #1, returning 4..6
  range uncovered so far ucr=8..10
  in if #2, returning nil
  range uncovered so far ucr=12..20
  in if #3, returning 14..20
ucrs after processing range 8..14=[1..3, 4..6, nil, 14..20]
ucrs after compact=[1..3, 4..6, 14..20]
```

```
covering range r=16..17
  range uncovered so far ucr=1..3
  in if #1, returning 1..3
  range uncovered so far ucr=4..6
  in if #1, returning 4..6
  range uncovered so far ucr=14..20
  in else, returning [14..16, 17..20]
ucrs after processing range 16..17=[1..3, 4..6, 14..16, 17..20]
ucrs after compact=[1..3, 4..6, 14..16, 17..20]
```

```
covering range r=20..20
  range uncovered so far ucr=1..3
  in if #1, returning 1..3
  range uncovered so far ucr=4..6
  in if #1, returning 4..6
  range uncovered so far ucr=14..16
  in if #1, returning 14..16
  range uncovered so far ucr=17..20
  in if #1, returning 17..20
ucrs after processing range 20..20=[1..3, 4..6, 14..16, 17..20]
ucrs after compact=[1..3, 4..6, 14..16, 17..20]
  #=> [1..3, 4..6, 14..16, 17..20]
```

Answer (score 3):

## Possible solution

Using this [range operator gem](https://github.com/monocle/range_operators), this script would (almost) return what you want.

It begins with `period`, and substracts every `incident` one after the other.

Since substracting a range from another can result in two ranges, the script actually begins with `[period]` and keeps an array of free incident ranges between iterations :

```
require 'range_operators'

incident_free = incidents.inject([period]) do |free_ranges, incident|
  free_ranges.flat_map do |free_range|
    free_range - incident
  end
end

p incident_free
#=> [2016-12-22 09:00:01 +0100..2016-12-22 12:59:59 +0100, 2016-12-22 15:30:01 +0100..2016-12-22 18:59:59 +0100]
```

## Notes

It complains that `Time#succ` is obsolete. You can either add

```
class Time
  def succ
    self+1
  end
end
```

to remove the deprecation warnings, or use a Gemfile with :

```
gem 'range_operators', :git => 'https://github.com/monocle/range_operators.git'
```

to install a newer version of the gem, with a fix for `Time`.

The script works with a resolution of 1 second, and the first range begins at `09:00:01` because there was an incident until `09:00:00`.