# Looking for an algorithm/data structure to store and search for data where multiple keys match the same node

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I have some data that maps ranges of numerical data to different colors. So 0.0-2.0 will be one color, while 2.1-4.0 will be a different color. I need a way to efficiently search for the appropriate color for a given value. e.g., If I search for 1.4, I should get the range 0.0-2.0.

I have an idea about how I would implement such a thing from scratch using some kind of binary search tree, but I'm wondering if there exists a better algorithm.

Comment: Tell us your idea.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1193522/1911064) related post?

Comment: @AxelKemper I have not, but that sounds very much like what I need. I'll investigate further, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your ranges can be arbitrary, then it is indeed complicated and the best solution might be to use a binary tree / binary search, as you suggested. Binary search is so fast that you can be sure it will perform well enough for almost whatever case you have. But it is more complex to implement, and not quite constant-time.

However, if your ranges are uniform like in your example (0-2, 2-4, 4-6, ...), or otherwise well-behaved, then you can just transform your number to the correct index. In your example, something like:

`f(x) = floor(x) / 2 - 1`

will map `x` to `0, 1, 2, ...`. After that you can just use a normal dictionary / map structure to map the indices to your colours. This would be a *O(1)* solution down to arithmetic operations.

Comment: That's interesting. I don't know if the ranges are strictly uniform but I suspect they might be for at least one use case.

Comment: @Mirrana It just boils down to this: Can you transform your input number into a unique index according to some mathematical function? If yes, then you can solve it in constant time. If not, then you have to look at your ranges, be it through a smart data structure like you suggested, or just naively checking one-by-one.

Comment: @Mirrana If you are not sure, you could always give more details about your problem / application and maybe you will get a more definite answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Berthur's suggestion is going to be fastest if the intervals are uniform and not overlapping.

Otherwise I highly recommend an interval tree.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree